# Ckeditor removing inline style and iframe

Tags: ckeditor

This is my config:
But still the editor removes the inline style and iframe tags.

```
config.allowedContent = true;

config.extraAllowedContent = 'iframe(*)[*]{*};style(*)[*]{*};img(*)[*]{*};span(*)[*]{*};p(*)[*]{*};div(*)[*]{*};li(*)[*]{*};ul(*)[*]{*}';
```

Comment: When you are using `config.allowedContent = true;` everything is allowed because ACF is disabled so there is absolutely no sense in extending the filter which is off anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure why these tags are gone and what type of configuration you have but try clearing browser's cache - https://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache as a start. Next thing is finding out when inline tags are removed. If you switch to source mode and tags are there but aren't there when you save data on server then your server-side code is removing these tags and not the editor.

Comment: @j.swiderski Hi,the code is saved in the database but when i reload the Ckeditor its gone.

Comment: In such a case please check your server-side code because if data is there in CKEditor when you press submit button then this is not the editor which removes these tags.

Comment: Actually the issue was in the CKEDITOR config, fixed now thanks